# Is it a good practice to instantiate an object with auto?

Tags: c++

**solution 1 :**

```
auto a = A()
```

**Solution 2 :**

```
A a;
```

I was wondering which one of the two solutions is the best manner to instantiate an object ?

I know that the **solution 1** calls the default constructor and then the copy constructor, but I really don't know if there is any advantages of writing that.

**Edit:**  I wrote a small class to test by my own and it appears that in accordance with the comments, these two "solutions" have exactly the same behavior.

```
class A
{ 
    public: 
    A(){
        std::cout <<"default_constructor\n";
    }
    A(const A &g){
        std::cout <<"copy_constructor\n";
    }
};
```

solution 1 :

> default_constructor

solution 2 :

> default_constructor

Comment: What you know about solution 1 isn't correct

Comment: Can you tell me please ?

Comment: There's no copy

Comment: no copy or no copy constructor ?

Comment: Well, it's in the name...

Comment: Why not `auto A{};`? Also see https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/

Comment: Didn't know that syntax @Petr

Comment: @Petr : What do you mean, `auto A{}` ? The intent is to define a variable `a` with type `A`. `auto` won't generate a variable name for you.

Comment: my personal rule is to never use `auto` when its only effect is that I'd have to spell out the type later in the same line as in `auto a = A();` vs `A a;`. `auto` wasnt invented to make you type more, but to make you type less

Comment: @MSalters, oh, indeed. Need to think before posting :)

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you should always use solution 2 for this case, as you have to define the type somewhere. I prefer using auto just in cases where the type is already set and I can avoid duplicate the type e.g. getting an element from an container

```
std::vector<double> myVector{0.0, 1.0};
auto firstElement = myVector.front();
```

or

```
auto myInt = static_cast<int>(2.0);
```

Comment: This is all subjective. But for what it's worth this is exactly my approach too. Some people take the notion of "consistency" too far and insist on `auto` everywhere just because they've used it somewhere. `auto main() -> int {}` ew!